# Should I ventilate my basement?

Tags: basement, ventilation

I'm finishing out a small room in my basement.  The house is built on the top of a hill, most of the basement is below grade made out of cinder block, but there is a garage door on one end that leads to the carport.  I'm in NJ, the basement stays about 65 in winter, 68 (degrees) in summer, absolutely no humidity problems year round.  Most of what I read about ventilating a basement is to get rid of humidity, I don't have that problem.  Just stale air.  There is an adjoining crawl space to the basement, that crawl space has a small fixed window just above grade.  I could put an exhaust fan there, I just don't want to introduce any humidity to the basement.  I assume an exhaust fan would pull air from the temp controlled upstairs, but I'm just not sure that will solve my problem.  Its hard to stay in the basement for any period of time, I don't know if its allergies or what, but I get a slight headache and semi-nauseous feeling.  My plan regarding the building out of the basement is to close off a 11x20 area from the rest of the basement, it would open up to the main floor of the house.  Is installing an exhaust fan in the crawl space the thing to do?  As I said, I don't want to introduce any more humidity or adversely effect the cool temperature of the basement.  Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but being unable to remain in the basement seems problematic. I would see about getting it inspected for any possible irritants.

Comment: I would [check your air quality](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/40562/23448)

Comment: Nausea and headaches are early indicators carbon monoxide poisoning, so I would be fairly cautious if you have a combustion source (furnace, water heater) in addition to the attached carport. Getting the air tested would definitely be preferable to internet speculation.